# Check multiple data in SQL table

Tags: c#, sql, mariadb, windows-forms-designer

I'm working on a project that uses C# (with windows form) and SQL.
I need to place objects in a certain position (chosen by the user).
Here's my SQL table : 
`Zone(int), 
 x(int), 
 y(int), 
 z(int), 
 ref(varchar), 
 size(int)`

So I have 4 variables for the location: `Zone`, `x`, `y`, and `z`.

Before placing an object I need to check if there's not already one at the location I want to put him.

Since I need to check multiple data I don't know if there is a better way to do it.

I don't know what I should use.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I saw a statement called "if exist" but i don't really understand how to use it with when trying to check multiple values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use like this

```
   insert into table1 (zone,x,...)
   select @zone,@x,....
   where not exists(select 1 from table1 where zone=@zone and x=@x and y=@y and z=@z)
```

or you can use `unique constraint` on your table.
example:

```
CREATE TABLE websites
( website_id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  website_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  server_name VARCHAR(20),
  creation_date DATE,
  CONSTRAINT websites_unique UNIQUE (website_name)
);
```

Comment: I think that the unique constraint could be great to use in the future.
I'm going to try the if exists method!
I will tell you if it works!

Comment: if youe problem solved . then Accept my answer please

Comment: I tried the if exists command but it's not working in my case,
So i used the Select method where i verify if the reader is empty or not.